# Dockerhub Automatic Build with Github LFS

Tags: github, docker

I want to introduce **Git LFS** in my github repository.

Does dockerhub automatic builds support **Git LFS**?
What happens if dockerhub `Automatic Build` checks out a **Git LFS** repository?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing regarding lfs in [`docker/hub-feedback`](https://github.com/docker/hub-feedback/search?q=lfs&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93).

Nor is there anything in [**docker/notary**](https://github.com/docker/notary) or [`docker/docs.docker.com`](https://github.com/docker/docs.docker.com), or [`docker/distribution`](https://github.com/docker/distribution)

The [Docker Hub Automatic build](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/) "allow[s] you to use Docker Hub’s build clusters to automatically create images from a GitHub or Bitbucket repository containing a Dockerfile".

Since Git LFS is only official on GitHub repos [is only official for the last 14 days](https://github.com/blog/2079-managing-large-files-with-git-lfs), and being [worked on for BitBucket](https://blog.bitbucket.org/2015/10/01/contributing-to-git-lfs/) (coming from their original [Git LOB](https://github.com/atlassian/git-lob) initiative), it seems safe to say LFS isn't yet supported by an Automatic build.

---

Update June 2016, [Andy Li](https://stackoverflow.com/users/267998/andy-li) reports [in the comments below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33327780/dockerhub-automatic-build-with-github-lfs/33327903?noredirect=1#comment63238397_33327903):

> There is now a feature request issue in docker/hub-feedback:

[Issue 500: "**Add support for Git LFS**"](https://github.com/docker/hub-feedback/issues/500).
It needs your support (or your Pull-Requests)

---

4 years later, Q4 2019, you might consider as an alternative **[GitHub Actions](https://github.com/features/actions)**. Check [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66303185/docker-copy-fails-github-actions-with-git-lfs/66453723#66453723) for more details on how to use git-lfs in them.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I am looking for someone who can say "Yes I tried - and I succeeded" or "Yes I tried - and I failed".

Comment: Git LFS has been official since April with the first release, it has been official to the public since October but the beta was so widely available that it's "official" timeline is rather misleading.  It's even been available in Travis-CI for  quite a while the beta was so popular.

Comment: There is now a feature request issue in docker/hub-feedback: https://github.com/docker/hub-feedback/issues/500 Let's thumb up it! ;)

Comment: @AndyLi Good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility (and I have thumbed up the GitHub issue)

Comment: As of November 2019, this is NOT supported.

Comment: @gregory I concur. 4 years later, there might be an alternative. I have edited my answer.

Comment: The GitHub Actions that were presented don't actually work with docker/git-lfs. That's because the docker action provided ignores the checkout action provided (it checks out again inside a VM, ignoring any parameters set in the first action). I'm fixing the answer with a link to a more detailed solution.

Comment: @roim Thank you for this edit! Very useful.