# Docker COPY fails Github actions with git lfs

Tags: git, docker, github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I am using Github actions to build docker images with a file from git lfs.
I have the following step:

```
     - 
        name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          lfs: true
      - 
        run: head something.json
```

Which prints the data correctly.

When I run the same command from my dockerfile in the build stage,
I get the following lfs metadata:

```
#7 [4/5] RUN head something.json
#7 sha256:***
#7 0.138 version https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1
#7 0.138 oid sha256:***
#7 0.138 size 1230424
#7 DONE 0.2s
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM bitnami/python:3.9.1

COPY . .

RUN head something.json
```

Action:

```
jobs:
  build-image:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - 
        name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          lfs: true
      - 
        run: head something.json
      -
        name: Set up QEMU
        uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v1
      -
        name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v1
      -
        name: Build and push
        id: docker_build
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        with:
          push: true
          file: Dockerfile
```

Why the docker build takes the metadata and not the actual file?

Comment: There's something here we're missing.  Your output shows step 4/5, but your Dockerfile has only 3 steps.  One of those missing steps is probably the issue.

Answer (score 1):

### The fix

Run this step after your git checkout:

```
- run: git lfs pull
```

And add to your docker build action:

```
with:
  context: .
```

Fully working example on this repo: https://github.com/roim/docker-action-lfs

### Why?

2 separate issues:

1. The docker build in `docker/build-push-action@v2` isn't using the git repo from the checkout action you specified. You can confirm by reading logs for that action and verifying it pulls a git repo again, into a new folder:

```
/usr/bin/docker buildx build --tag ***/www:latest --iidfile *** --secret id=*** --file ./Dockerfile --push https://github.com/***/www.git#heads/main
#1 [internal] load git source https://github.com/***/www.git#heads/main
#1 sha256:***
#1 0.013 Initialized empty Git repository in /var/lib/buildkit/runc-overlayfs/snapshots/snapshots/1/fs/
#1 0.334 ***    refs/heads/main
#1 0.622 From https://github.com/***/www
#1 0.622  * [new branch]      main       -> heads/main
#1 0.623  * [new branch]      main       -> origin/main
```

2. [The default checkout action seems to fetch LFS objects, but not resolve them in the working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61463578/github-actions-actions-checkoutv2-lfs-true-flag-not-converting-pointers-to-act). Explicitly running `git lfs pull` will fix that.

--

Note that there is [a long standing issue reported in 2015](https://github.com/docker/hub-feedback/issues/500) where DockerHub doesn't support git-lfs--that's specific to DockerHub, not github actions.

As to why the default context doesn't respect lfs, [I opened a new issue for that](https://github.com/docker/build-push-action/issues/312).

Comment: Thanks! I've spent hours trying to figure this out. Your solution worked for me. 
Regarding the second issue (GitHub Action doesn't pull LFS resources): it seems this has been fixed by now, I didn't encounter this issue when using the `ubuntu-latest` worker.